# Ruby and mysql2: TLS version used does not meet minimal requirements for this server

Tags: ruby, azure, ssl, azure-sql-database, mysql2

I am using Ruby 2.3 and Rails 4.2. gem mysql 0.5.3 is installed. When I am trying to deploy the application to Azure Database for MySQL (restriction TLS1.2) and got the error "SSL verification failed" after configuration of database.yml. Then, I just tried to do single connection in command line with the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-ruby. The error is:

```
$ ruby createtable.rb
..........start to connect to database.
TLS version used does not meet minimal requirements for this server. Please use a higher TLS version and retry.
Done.
```

How do I fix this issue?

By the way, I installed MySQL Community Server 8.0.22 on Azure VM, which is for web server. Connecting to remove MySQL server using Workbench with SSL is working.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Configure SSL connectivity in your application to securely connect to Azure Database for MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl)

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) to setup the right SSL/TLS to your environment.